# I have two div elements that I want both to CSS pulsate when hovering either

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I have two div elements that I want both to puslate (CSS animation) if mouse hovers on any one of them. There a simple code following. In my page they are not next each other. The above code does not works.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GcyqL/1/

**CSS:**

```
#counter {
   width:120px;
   height:25px;
   text-align: center;
   border-style: solid;
   border-width: 1px;
   background-color: rgb(142, 197, 255);
   font-weight: bold;
}

#mem_val {
   width:120px;
   height:25px;
   text-align: center;
   border-style: solid;
   border-width: 1px;
   background-color: rgb(142, 197, 255);
   font-weight: bold;
}

div.intro:hover{
   -webkit-animation: pulsate 1s infinite alternate;
   -moz-animation: pulsate 1s infinite alternate;
   -animation: pulsate 1s infinite alternate;
   text-shadow: 0 0 8px #ccc;
}

@-webkit-keyframes pulsate {
   from { box-shadow: 0 0 10px #333; }
   to { box-shadow: 0 0 20px #c00; }
}

@-moz-keyframes pulsate {
   from { box-shadow: 0 0 10px #333; }
   to { box-shadow: 0 0 20px #c00; }
}

@keyframes pulsate {
   from { box-shadow: 0 0 10px #333; }
   to { box-shadow: 0 0 20px #c00; }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="mem_val" class="intro" >mem_val</div><br><br>
<div id="counter" class="intro">counter</div><br><br>
```

Comment: I don't see what is not working

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do it only with CSS, you can add them both to the same container and use the container's `hover` selector.

Notice that this solution will make the `hover` animation even if the container is being hovered outside of these two elements. You can walk around this issue with a little trick that'll make the container stay "invisible", although it might be a bit non-flexible.

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/itay1989/GcyqL/6/)

```
#container {
    width:0;
    height:0;
    overflow: visible;
}

/* Old selector: div.intro:hover */
#container:hover div.intro {
    -webkit-animation: pulsate 1s infinite alternate;
    -moz-animation: pulsate 1s infinite alternate;
    -animation: pulsate 1s infinite alternate;
    text-shadow: 0 0 8px #ccc;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add jQuery and here's a solution, [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/slash197/GcyqL/4/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.pulsate').hover(
        function(){
            $('.pulsate').addClass('intro');
        },
        function(){
            $('.pulsate').removeClass('intro');
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: Do you have to use each? Why not just `$('.pulsate').addClass('intro');`

Answer (score 0):

Just put them inside a container with `display:inline;` and then use

```
#container:hover div {
    //plusate...
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/GcyqL/8/

Pure css.