# How can I apply the same jQuery hover animation to two divs of different height side-by-side?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, jquery-hover, hoverintent

I have a menu `<div>` with a shorter handle `<div>` to the right of it (see below).  This loads off to the left of the screen minus a `5px` sliver of the menu `<div>` and the whole handle `<div>`.  I want the whole container to slide onto the screen when the mouse hovers either portion, and off the screen when it leaves both portions.

This works except when the mouse goes from the handle to the menu.  There is a brief moment where the `mouseleave` from the handle and the `mouseenter` from the menu fire.  I have tried to `.stop(true)` the current animation on the container, but there is still a hesitation in the animation.

[image: Menu Sample]

`#slideout-nav` contains both elements (and transparent space below the handle, which I do not want to trigger the animation).
`#slideout-menu-container` is the left portion.
`#slideout-handle` is the right portion.

```
$('#slideout-menu-container').addClass('slideout-hover');
$('#slideout-handle').addClass('slideout-hover');

var slideIn = function () {
    $('#slideout-nav').stop(true);
    $('#slideout-nav').animate({
        left: '0px'
    });
};

var slideOut = function () {
    $('#slideout-nav').stop(true);
    $('#slideout-nav').animate({
        left: distance * -1 + 'px'
    });
};

$('.slideout-hover').hoverIntent(slideIn, slideOut);
```

Is there a more elegant way to accomplish this?

**Update**

HTML:

```
<div id="slideout-nav">
    <div id="slideout-handle">+</div>
    <div id="slideout-menu-container">
        <ul>
            <li><a>Home</a></li>
            <li><a>Models</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#slideout-nav {
    z-index: 99;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 225px;
}

#slideout-handle {
    float: right;
    padding: 10px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

#slideout-menu-container {
    overflow: hidden;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the markup?

Comment: @NathanP. Added the markup and some styling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a solution to this based on an answer to another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18547276/778427).

I set the containing `<div>` to have a `height` and `width` of `0` with `overflow: visible`.  Then I gave the containing `<div>` the hover event.  This ensures that the event is only triggered when the mouse enters or leaves its children (my menu and handle `<div>`s).

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qYUKS/) for posterity.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="menu">Menu</div>
    <div id="handle">+</div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
var slideIn = function () {
    $('#container').stop(true);
    $('#container').animate({
        left: '0px'
    }, 'fast');
};

var slideOut = function () {
    $('#container').stop(true);
    $('#container').animate({
        left: '-190px'
    }, 'fast');
};


$('#container').hover(slideIn, slideOut);
```

**CSS:**

```
#container {
    width:0;
    height:0;
    overflow:visible;
    position:absolute;
    left:-190px;
}

#handle {
    padding:10px;
    width:auto;
    height:auto;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    font-size:18px;
    color:#FFF;
    display:inline-block;
    border-bottom-right-radius:3px;

}

#menu {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    width:195px;
    height:300px;
    float:left;
    display:inline-block;
    border-bottom-right-radius:3px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I got you problem. I made some changes in your css (maybe it just fits the jsFiddle needs) :

```
#slideout-nav {
    z-index: 99;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: -200px; /* Here */
    width: 225px;
}
```

And in the JS :

```
$('#slideout-menu-container').addClass('slideout-hover');
$('#slideout-handle').addClass('slideout-hover');

var isAnimated = false;
var mouserOverHandle = false;

var slideIn = function () {
    if (!isAnimated) {
        isAnimated = true;
        $('#slideout-nav').animate({
            left: '0px'
        }, function () {isAnimated = false;});
    }
};

var slideOut = function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        if (!isAnimated && !mouseOverHandle) {
            isAnimated = true;
            $('#slideout-nav').animate({
                left: '-200px'
            }, function () {isAnimated = false;});
        }
    }, 10);
};

$('#slideout-handle').hover(function () {mouseOverHandle = true;}, function () {mouseOverHandle = false;});
$('.slideout-hover').hover(slideIn, slideOut);
```

I added a lock (`isAnimated`) to prevent the menu from sliding in other direction when it is already sliding.

And, the tricky part I think it can be improved, I added a timer to the slideOut function, because we have to know (when leaving the `menu-container` div) if we are over the handle or no. So the timer is just here to "wait" the event hover over the handle to be fired.

Without the timer (and the `mouseOverHandle` var) the menu slides out when your mouse goes over the handle from the menu-container. Feel free to remove it if it is not a matter for you.

See the jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/R7bwt/1/).

Comment: The problem with this approach is that the menu gets stuck in the "slid out" position if you move your mouse off of it before the slideout animation finishes. I also want the menu to slide back in immediately if the mouse is moved off of it while it's sliding out, and vice versa.  That is why I think my actual approach to it is wrong.

Comment: @Glendon Just remove the lock then, but keep the mouseOverHandle part.